# how to get lookup field value from entity object?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a list of "Participants",which is an entity. In that entity one lookup is there. how to get the Id,LogicalName values?
I was trying like this. but `ContId` is `undefined`

```
function GetTrips(contactId) {
    debugger;
    var participant = RetrieveCrmRecords("new_participant", null, null, null, null, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < participant.results.length; i++) {
        var ContId = participant.results[i].new_TripPerticipants.Id;
       //===================
    }
```

from that `RetrieveCrmRecords` I got following results: here `new_TripParticipants` is the lookup field.

[image]

Comment: is this typo in your actual code or just in your question (e <> a)?
new_PerticipantsContact.Id >>> new_ParticipantsContact.Id

Comment: What language is this? What does `RetrieveCrmRecords` do?

Comment: javascript.  The "debugger" keyword gives it away.  I had the same initial question.

Comment: At any rate, I would have expected your code to work.  What do you get when you step into the line "var ContId" and evaluate "participant.results[i].new_TripPerticipants" and "participant.results[i]" ?  In VS, the shortcut is often mapped to CTRL+D,Q

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a spelling typo.  Use

```
var ContId = participant.results[i].new_TripParticipants.Id;
```